# Badges links in achievements are broken

Tags: support, bug, android-app, stack-overflow-app

If you just earned a new badge and got the notification while using the Stack Overflow app it will go to a page with the following relevant message.

> Question not found. It might be deleted

See screenshot below

[image: Achievements]

[image: Broken page]

Comment: Another bug that is still happening after 3 years being reported. Anyone?